# Remove Focus on any TextArea on Dialog

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, content-management-system

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do on this jquery diag, i want to disable focus on any textarea inside this dialog

```
  $(function() {
  $( "#edit_triviadiag").dialog({
  height: 550,
    width: 640,
      autoOpen:false,
      autoresize:true,
  modal: true

 });
 });

 </script>
```

Comment: i want it to not focus to any textarea

Comment: When you say you don't want it to focus on any text area, do you mean you don't want any textarea to be focused when the dialog loads? Or that you don't want anyone to be able to enter text in any textarea in the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the focus on every textarea inside the dialog, you can do this

`$('#edit_triviadiag textarea').attr('readonly', 'readonly');`

I hope this helps you